# Auditing fields not automatically filled by JPA in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, auditing

I have the following entity, which reflects some kind of background task and gonna be updated. I thought using the JPA auditing would be useful so I included it like this:

```
@Entity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name = "FOO")
public class FooJob{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private long id;

    @LastModifiedDate
    @Column(name = "FINISHED", nullable = false)
    private LocalDateTime finished;

    ...

}

@Repository
public interface FooJobRepository
    extends JpaRepository<FooJob, Long>,
        JpaSpecificationExecutor<FooJob> {}
```

and I have enabled the `@EnableJpaAuditing` on the spring-boot application

spring version:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.0</version>
    <relativePath />
</parent>
```

But when running the code like this:

```
@Service
@Transactional
/*package*/ class FooJobService{
   public void run() {
     FooJob job = createJob();
     ....
   }

   private FooJob createJob(){
      FooJob job = new FooJob();
      job.setSomeValue("123");
      //Do not set "finished" date here
      repo.saveAndFlush(job); //THIS LINE THROWS EXCEPTION
   }
}
```

Ill get the following exception:

> org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: not-null
> property references a null or transient value :
> my.package.entity.FooJob.finished; nested exception is
> org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a
> null or transient value : my.package.entity.FooJob.finished

Why does this not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to Entity if you only update finished date:

```
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
```

Comment: Why is that? I also do have a "BaseEntity" (class) annotated as "MappedSuperclass". Every other entity extending (inherits standard audit fields) that works out of the box, as the "BaseEntity" has "createdAt", "createdBy". "lastModified", "lastModifiedBy". The "BaseEntity" does not have "EntityListeners", but it still works.

Comment: If you have a Base Entity you must add in this base class. my exemple:                                            @MappedSuperclass
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public abstract class Baseentity {

Comment: But the BaseEntity works without @EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class), why is that?

Comment: Works without auditing.

Comment: Not for me. And I need to have EnableJpaAuditing on the application or configuration class. But for test I am getting now: 
Invalid bean definition with name 'jpaAuditingHandler' defined in null

Answer (score 2):

You need to annotate `@EnableJpaAuditing` in your main class or a Configuration class (a class with `@Configuration`)

and have to annotate Entity class with `@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)`.

Comment: "EnableJpaAuditing" is not necessary to put on the "Configuration" annotated class. It also works having it on the "Application" class with the "SpringBootApplication" annotation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add more annotations to your entity so it can be audited (at least `@Audited`, `@AuditTable` and `@EntityListeners`.

Example:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "my_table")
@AuditTable("my_table_audit")
@Audited
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class MyEntity{
  @Column(name = "created_date", nullable = false)
  @CreatedDate
  private Date createdDate;
  @Column(name = "modified_date")
  @LastModifiedDate
  private Date modifiedDate;
  @Column(name = "created_by")
  @CreatedBy
  private String createdBy;
  @Column(name = "modified_by")
  @LastModifiedBy
  private String modifiedBy;
  @Version
  private Long version;
```

Also I'm not sure if `@LastModifiedDate` can be used with type `LocalDateTime`.

You also need an auditing framework like *Hibernate Envers*.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

In case you are using Hibernate *Envers* and *MySQL* the auditing should be like this:

```
CREATE TABLE revinfo
(
    revision_number integer AUTO_INCREMENT,
    REVTSTMP bigint,
    CONSTRAINT revinfo_pkey PRIMARY KEY (revision_number)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS my_table
(
    ...
    created_date                datetime DEFAULT now(),
    modified_date               datetime DEFAULT now(),
    created_by                  VARCHAR(100)  NULL,
    modified_by                 VARCHAR(100)  NULL,
    version                     INT           NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS my_table_audit
(
    ...
    created_date                datetime,
    modified_date               datetime,
    created_by                  VARCHAR(100),
    modified_by                 VARCHAR(100),
    version                     INT,
    revision_number             integer,
    revision_type               smallint,
    FOREIGN KEY fk_my_table_audit_rev_num (revision_number) REFERENCES REVINFO (revision_number)
);
```

Comment: I am not using envers to "remember" states. I just wanted to update the "finished" according to the last modified date value.